# What's the word for when two worlds coexist in the same space simultaneously but one is hidden or veiled from the other?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, writing-advice

Consider how the wizarding world is hidden from the muggle world in the Harry Potter/ Wizarding World universe.
Or in Hell Boy II. The troll market is hidden under a bridge. Red can see it but it's veiled from the human eye.
Shadow Hunters. Clary can see the runes outside of the nightclub but Simon can't see them.
I have been referring to it as a troll market concept but I feel like there is a better word(s) for it.

Comment: Parallel or alternate universes, maybe? Take a look at the examples here and see if they fit your criteria: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_universes_in_fiction

Comment: TV Tropes has [Phantom Zone](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PhantomZone), [The Masquerade](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Masquerade), [Invisible to Normals](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/InvisibleToNormals), [Wainscot Society](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WainscotSociety), and probably more tropes. Not sure any of these is an exact match.

Comment: Wainscot society actually seems to pretty close to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something here, but this is describing an "**invisible**" or "**hidden**" world, where "invisible/hidden" is usually qualified by such phrases as "to the normal eye/from the normal eye" or "to/from those who do not have the power"; "to/from all but the chosen few", etc. or "except on midsummer's eve" etc...

**invisible** and **hidden** have their normal meanings.

Comment: I'm looking for the actual word. Invisible seems to more of a word to describe it. Like the word wet describes a pool. My friend suggested the word realm, but in my head that doesn't quite seem to fit either.

Answer (score 0):

The following term might be used, as, the most often, those more or less hidden entities are considered to be  unacceptable from the point of view of decent society, or barely acceptable, or at times, just not conferring the idea of people having a pleasant station in life.

> (**SOED**) **underworld** **4** A sphere or region (regarded as) lying below the ordinary one. Also, a lower, or the lowest, stratum of society.
> • T. BULLEN The begrimed … toilers … in the underworld of engines and boilers.
> • *attrib.: San Diego* A playwright … solicits underworld figures to back its latest play.

Comment: The word 'underworld' seems to have a more negative tone then what I'm looking for.